# Gnome-Shell Logout

Tags: gnome, logout

The latest version of Gnome-shell starts to display (the top bar appears briefly) but I then get logged out. This happens when I start it with "gnome-shell --replace". Any idea how to make it behave properly? Laptop is a MSI U21, an0d I run with a 'nomodeset' startup option. Without this option the screen clears to just wallpaper and stays that way.

Gnome-shell v2.31.5
Kernel 2.6.35-27 (& 28 as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the boot-up option "nomodeset" seems to correct this problem. The MSI U210 needs "nomodeset" to handle an external monitor correctly, and so I have its set as a default. When I booth without it, gnome-shell behaves normally. It sounds like there is a fix for the U21p nomodeset requirement in Natty, so hopefully I'll be able to work as I wish then.

Answer (score 0):

You could try starting it in its own session instead of replacing your current WM with it. There's a package in the repos for that in Maverick--gnome3-session--but if you want it to start a compiled-from-git version instead you'll have to edit the session file (`/usr/share/xsessions/gnome3` maybe) or create a symlink to the version you want to start (`sudo rm /usr/bin/gnome-shell` should remove the old version of the shell from the repos, and then `sudo ln -s ~/path/to/your/gnome-shell /usr/bin/gnome-shell` should link to it).

Comment: I get the same behaviour when starting it as its own shell (started from the repos, not built by hand).